# Creating invariant position scale labels in the margins of a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My goal was to create a scale label in the margins of a ggplot, and this scale label should be invariant in position across graphs (such that cycling through similar graphs does not show the scale label moving).

This task has been considerably harder than I expected because ggplot:

1. Does not have a scale label concept,
2. Does not easily allow for annotating in the margins,
3. Insists on annotations being located in a data-dependent (i.e., not position invariant) way

**EDIT: For clarity, I am specifically after a scale *pole* label. See the resulting ggplot for an example.**

Here is my solution that works, albeit in a hacky way:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

dat = data.frame("Country" = c(rep("USA",50),
                               rep("Canada",50),
                               rep("Japan",50),
                               rep("Poland",50),
                               rep("Germany",50)),
                 "Outcome" = c(rnorm(n = 50, mean = 4.0, sd = 1.0),
                               rnorm(n = 50, mean = 5.0, sd = 0.5),
                               rnorm(n = 50, mean = 3.0, sd = 1.5),
                               rnorm(n = 50, mean = 4.5, sd = 1.0),
                               rnorm(n = 50, mean = 4.5, sd = 1.5))
)

myfunction = function(data, IV, DV, varlevels){
  
  # bumpsize is the hacky code that gets it to work
  # parameters need fine-tuning for perfect consistency but good enough here
  bumpsize = .45-(.06*length(varlevels))  
  
  # compute mean for plotting
  as_tibble(dat) %>%
    group_by({{IV}}) %>%
    summarise(Outcome = mean({{DV}},na.rm=T)) %>%
    
  # do the plotting  
  ggplot(mapping = aes({{IV}}, Outcome, fill = {{IV}})) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = {{varlevels}}) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1:7), limits = c(1,7), oob = scales::squish) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
    annotation_custom(
      grob = textGrob(label = "Good", gp = gpar(col = "grey50"), rot = 90),
      ymin = 6, ymax = 7, xmin = bumpsize, xmax = bumpsize) +
    annotation_custom(
      grob = textGrob(label = "Bad", gp = gpar(col = "grey50"), rot = 90),
      ymin = 1, ymax = 2, xmin = bumpsize, xmax = bumpsize)
}



myfunction(data = dat, IV = Country, DV = Outcome, varlevels =  c("USA","Canada","Japan","Poland","Germany"))

ggsave("outcome_by_country.png", dpi = 300, units = "in", height= 5.89, width = 6.69)
```

**My question:**
Is there a way to achieve invariant position scale labels without resorting to a hacky variable-level equation as currently implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two 'magic' positions that are recognised in ggplot are `-Inf` and `Inf` that are always placed at the minimum and maximum position in a panel. We can use this to annotate the `"Good"` and `"Bad"` text in the margins of the plot. We can use the `hjust` parameter to determine how far the labels should be from the horizontal lines of the (secondary and primary) x-axis. The `vjust` parameter determines how far out in the margin the text is placed. This would need to depend on how wide the axis text labels are, but seeing as you're fixing these to `1:7`, the proposed value for `vjust` seems appropriate. The `hjust`/`vjust` parameters apply to the text size, so these are not dependent on the data being plotted in the bars.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

dat = data.frame("Country" = c(rep("USA",50),
                               rep("Canada",50),
                               rep("Japan",50),
                               rep("Poland",50),
                               rep("Germany",50)),
                 "Outcome" = c(rnorm(n = 50, mean = 4.0, sd = 1.0),
                               rnorm(n = 50, mean = 5.0, sd = 0.5),
                               rnorm(n = 50, mean = 3.0, sd = 1.5),
                               rnorm(n = 50, mean = 4.5, sd = 1.0),
                               rnorm(n = 50, mean = 4.5, sd = 1.5))
)

myfunction = function(data, IV, DV, varlevels){
  # compute mean for plotting
  as_tibble(dat) %>%
    group_by({{IV}}) %>%
    summarise(Outcome = mean({{DV}},na.rm=T)) %>%
    
    # do the plotting  
    ggplot(mapping = aes({{IV}}, Outcome, fill = {{IV}})) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = {{varlevels}}) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1:7), limits = c(1,7), oob = scales::squish) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
    annotate(
      "text", x = -Inf, y = c(-Inf, Inf), label = c("Bad", "Good"), angle = 90, 
      hjust = c(-0.3, 1.3), # Some offset from c(0, 1), here: 0.3
      vjust = -1.7
    )
}



myfunction(data = dat, IV = Country, DV = Outcome, varlevels =  c("USA","Canada","Japan","Poland","Germany"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>